# TICK stack - adding multiple influxdb sources to chronograf / kapacitor

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, kapacitor, chronograf

This is my first time posting to stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance if I am not following certain protocols. I will fix and / or expand my question as needed.

I am trying to add 2 different influxdb sources that are hosted on 2 different servers to chronograf kapacitor but I cannot get it working.

**Can you connect to 2 different influxdb instances through the UI?**

**How do you configure kapacitor.conf to read from 2 different influxdb instances**?

Through the Chronograf UI I can get either source working correctly but not both at the same time.  This seems to be expected through the UI so I must be missing something.

If I set the sources in kapacifor.conf, chronograf does not read from them.  There are also no errors in kapacitor logs.

This is my kapacitor.conf influxdb settings that do not work:

```
[[influxdb]]
  enabled = true
  default = true
  name = "localcluster"
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  username = ""
  password = ""
  timeout = 0

[[influxdb]]
  enabled = true
  default = false
  name = "remoteCluster"
  urls = ["http://remotehost:8086"]
  username = ""
  password = ""
  timeout = 0
```

I have read the documentation and also have the latest TICK stack packages.

I have also searched online and found some references that look like my configuration and are said to work, but they do not seem to work for me.

TICK stack host information:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
telegraf-1.9.1-1.x86_64
influxdb-1.7.2-1.x86_64
chronograf-1.7.4-1.x86_64
kapacitor-1.5.1-1.x86_64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did read this post https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/911 which is what I based my kapacitor.conf on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working but I am not sure if the configuration is recommended:

- Add a new InfluxDB connection through the Chronograf web UI.
- Do not create another Kapacitor Connection as only one can be active at a time.
- In the graph Queries tab, select the new 
  InfluxDB connection from the drop down list.
  Metrics from the alternate InfluxDB instance will appear and can be queried.